# C# - Are there any restrictions on the permitted operations when running an external .exe file?

Tags: c#

I have a C#/.NET GUI application
I also have a .exe script, which accepts two parameters, a file location and a string parameter

Run in cmd like so

```
script.exe C:/data/data1.e Analyze
```

where `data1.e` is a custom particular binary file format, and `Analyze` is just a action parameter

In my application, I need to call this script. I'm doing the following

```
    System.Diagnostics.Process process1 = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    process1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    process1.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\data\script.exe";
    process1.StartInfo.Arguments = @"C:\data\data1.e Analyze";
    process1.Start();
    string output = process1.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
    process1.WaitForExit();
    process1.Close();
```

The `output` parameter gives me the error `Unable to open .e file`

**Question**
Are there any restrictions on the files C# allows external **.exe** files to run?

Comment: The only restriction is:  the .exe has to be a valid Windows application.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you use `C:/data/data1.e` to call from cmd while you use `C:\data\data1.e` for Process? Sounds like an issue in your script.exe to me, not a problem with Process.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question